# fastapi openapi doc for arbitrary request form

Tags: forms, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

How can I define an endpoint that accepts arbitrary form inputs so that it's correctly reflected in the generated FastAPI openapi docs?

So, I can do something like this to get the form:

```
@app.post("/foo")
async def dofoo(request:Request):
    form = await request.form()
```

But the openapi docs generated by FastAPI don't then indicate in any way that arbitrary form data is accepted. Nor can I figure out how to create an example for it to show up in openapi docs, either.

Is there any way to achieve this? Perhaps by declaring the accepted input in some way with Pydantic, or customizing the generated openapi doc?

I've checked a number of examples but they are about a different case when the number of and names of form inputs are known. Whereas in this case, the form keys cannot be known in advance, and neither can we know how many there'll be.

Some other examples out there specify how to do this with JSON body. But in this case the input is form, not a JSON body.

Comment: can you post the curl you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to show an arbitrary form in doc, as doc is made for defined input.

However, you can change your input to receive a `Dict` in the post Body , and you can send whatever params you want inside it.